# Django Template block tag

Tags: django, templates, tags, block

How many different block tags like these exist?

```
{% block %}
```

In other words if I have a parent template and child templates with multiple block tags. How does Django know where to insert if not by different block tag names?

Or can I customize like:

```
{% block_mytag_1 %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of these will work.

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/#topics-templates) clearly explains this - you need to give each block in your parent template a different name:

```
{% block maincontent %}
```

This will be filled by whatever block in your child template has the same name.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing. I read the django book section on Templates from start to beginning.  If I ask questions about it here I did either not find it and/or overlooked it. It is very complex to learn django and python and it is great to have this quick and great help. And I think these questions can be valuable for future students.

Answer (score 1):

You need [this template documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/#topics-templates), particularly the part on [Template Inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/#id1).